# Necessary and sufficient condition for unique minimum spanning tree

Tags: graphs, spanning-trees

This is an exercise problem (Ex.3) from the excellent lecture note by Jeff Erickson [Lecture 20: Minimum Spanning Trees [Fa’13]](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/20-mst.pdf)
.

> Prove that an edge-weighted graph $G$ has a unique minimum spanning tree if and only if the
>   following conditions hold
>
> - For any partition of the vertices of $G$ into two subsets, the minimum-weight edge with one endpoint in each subset is unique.
> - The maximum-weight edge in any cycle of $G$ is unique.

Consider the "$\Rightarrow$" direction and the following graph $G$.

[image: mst]

$G$ has a unique MST. However, for the partition $\{A\}$ and $\{B,C\}$, the minimum-weight crossing edge is *not* unique.

> Did I misunderstand some points? Or if there are flaws in the theorem, how can we fix it?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a mistake. Try to figure out what version of the exercise is correct. For example, it seems that the second condition is indeed necessary.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, the second condition is not necessary either.
Consider the graph {(A,B,1), (A,C,1), (A,D,1), (B,D,10), (D,C,10)}. It
also has a minimum spanning tree composed of edges connected to A. But there
is a cycle with 2 maximum weight edges (and the first condition is not
met either).  CC @YuvalFilmus

Comment: @jeffe, what do you think? ;)

Comment: I think the second should be in "in any _chordless_ cycle" (so a minimal cycle in the sense that it doesn't include smaller ones as induced subgraphs). The first condition seems significantly wrong. For example take $G$ to be any tree where all edge weights are $1$, then $G$ has a unique MST (itself), but any partition with more than one edge crossing it has several minimum weight edges.

Comment: Actually, scrap my idea about the cycle condition, if we a cycle with edge weights all "big" (say 2 for argument's sake), then add a vertex connected to every vertex in the cycle, where all these edges have weight "small" (~1), then there is a unique MST, but the original cycle certainly doesn't have a unique maximum weight edge, and also has no chords.

Comment: @LukeMathieson MST is such a deceptively simple concept that I often get simple, plausible, but wrong proofs about it.

Comment: Oops!  Yes, this is a bug.  (Note to self: Change every instance of "Prove" to "Prove or disprove".)

Comment: @JeffE Thanks for your reply. Both my teacher and I (as a TA) enjoy your lecture notes. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my own question by simply copying the comment made by @JeffE, the author of the lecture note：

> Oops! Yes, this is a bug. (Note to self: Change every instance of "Prove" to "Prove or disprove".) – JeffE